# Activerecord - how to made this?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

Everyday, I need to run the a script and send all of my users an 'exam' or set of questions. I have modelled as class 'Exam' which subclasses ActiveRecord::Base. Now, how do I send user's instances of Exam?

What I was thinking was create a new class called 'ExamInstance' which would have a reference to 'Exam' and the user.

I am new to SQL and ActiveRecord so if someone can help me better model this so I can avoid problems later on or just give me some insight, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest just use `has_many :through` create a model `UserExam` for many to many relation between `exam` and `user`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_exams
  has_many :exams, :through => :users_exams
end
 
class UserExam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :exams
end
 
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_exams
  has_many :users, :through => :users_exams
end
```

For more information on [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'ExamUser' model to keep track of exam and the corresponding users references. The model skeleton will look something like:

```
class ExamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You could then loop through the records of this table to send your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your new model like  this..

```
  class ExamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user  # user has many exams
   belongs_to :exam  #  exam has many users
  end
```